# Under the plan proposed by Egypt how much influence would the existing Hamas government have over the new government of experts?

Tags: palestine, 2023-israel-hamas-war, hamas, egypt

> It calls for an initial cease-fire of up to two weeks during which
> Palestinian militants would free 40 to 50 hostages, among them women,
> the sick and the elderly, in return for the release of 120-150
> Palestinians from Israeli prisons, the Egyptian official said. He
> spoke on condition of anonymity to discuss the ongoing talks.
>
> At the same time, negotiations would continue on extending the
> cease-fire and the release of more hostages and bodies held by
> Palestinian militants, he said.
>
> **Egypt and Qatar would also work with all Palestinian factions,
> including Hamas, to agree on the establishment of a government of
> experts, he said. The government would rule Gaza and the West Bank for
> a transitional period as Palestinian factions settle their disputes
> and agree on a roadmap to hold presidential and parliamentary
> elections, he added.**

https://www.cp24.com/world/egypt-floats-ambitious-plan-to-end-israel-hamas-war-as-death-toll-in-an-israeli-strike-rises-to-106-1.6700918

Under the plan proposed by Egypt how much influence would the existing Hamas government have over the new government of experts? I couldn't find any detail on how the new government would be different from the Palestinian Authority and how it would solve the problem of Hamas ruling over Gaza, it doesn't say if Hamas would have a say in this new government and what power they would have. Egypt suggested forming a government of experts, but I am not sure what they mean by that.

Comment: From your quote: "He spoke on condition of anonymity to discuss the ongoing talks." This is an ongoing event and I think that is all the information that is currently publically available.